# Properties of logarithmic mean.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis

I have been studying the logarithmic mean for the last few days now. Could someone please help me with the following two questions?

1) We know that the log mean is in between the geometric mean and the arithmetic mean. In fact, there are a number of papers in the literature which proved that sharper bounds exist for log mean. I want to know whether this log mean is closer to the arithmetic mean or to the geometric mean?

2) Let $\{X_n\}$ be i.i.d positive random variables. Let $Y_n$ be the log mean of $\{X_1,...,X_n\}$. What can we say (if at all we can say anything) about the convergence of $\{Y_n\}$?

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem which has been addressed many times in heat exchanger calculations since the logarithmic mean difference temperature makes equations much more difficult.

I give you below two very good approximations which are widely used in this area (the first on is by Paterson, the send one by Chen)  $$\text{LM} \simeq  \frac{\text{AM}}{3}+\frac{2 \text{ }\text{GM}}{3}$$ $$\text{LM}\simeq \sqrt[3]{\text{AM} \text{ } \text{GM}^2}$$ If you wish more, just post (it is a problem I currently work in order to improve the efficiency of  time consuming simulations).

**These formulas were established for the $AM, GM, LM$ fo two numbers**.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I wanted to know whether L.M is closer to G.M or to A.M?

Comment: And what about the second part?

Comment: from this information we can only infer that L.M is closer to G.M for 2 numbers, but what about n arguments? Do you know any answer to the second part of my question?